# How to write the set builder notation for this DFA.

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

Please see the image for the DFA

[image]

So far I have the following notation but am unsure how to convert the text part into a more mathematical notation. I'm also not sure if I am allowed to use the star closure of the alphabet $\{0,1\}^*$

$w \:\varepsilon \:\{0,1\}^* :\:$ number of 1s is even, number of 0s congruent with 1(mod3)

&&

$w \:\varepsilon \:\{0,1\}^* :\:$ number of 1s is odd, number of 0s congruent with 2(mod3)

Thank you

Comment: Sorry boss, not sure where to start.

Comment: Yes q5 is the initial state and q1, q3 are the final states. From q5 the input 001 would take us through the sequence {q5, q1, q2, q3} which would be accepted right?

Comment: I think the accepted squences are of the form $0\underbrace{111111}_{\text{evennumber of} 1s}0\underbrace{1111}_{\text{evennumber of} 1s}0 \ \ \underbrace{1111111111}_{\text{evennumber of} 1s}...$

Comment: Okay, let me look into that. Thanks Jean

Comment: 1) There are other accepted strings with an **odd number** of zeros... but still intertwined with strings having an even number of ones. 2) I have included your DFA in the text of your question.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I noticed the odd numbers of zeros. Also '0000' is accepted, i'm struggling to find a set all the solutions fall into.

Comment: Indeed the case of a first sequence beginning by an even number of zeros is accepted by the automaton. If such an initial sequence is followed by a sequence of (an even number of 1s, the possible further sequences of zeros should have an odd number of zeros.

Comment: Try this: annotate each state with the number of 1's, modulo 2, leading up to it, and with the number of 0's modulo 3. Show that these annotations work, in the sense that if you leave a state and later get back to it, the annotations are still correct. Verify that all six possible combinations are covered by the six states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look first at the structure of the cycles in this DFA. You can get from any state back to itself with two 1s or three 0s, but you can also break out of those cycles into larger cycles. Because of the symmetry of the cycles between states, any input with the number of 0s being a multiple of three and the number of 1s being a multiple of two leads you back to the same state again.

With that information we can look now at all inputs that land us on accepting state q1. From starting state q5, a single 0 gets us to q1, and because of the symmetry mentioned above, so will any string containing an even number of 1s and any number of 0s such that the number is congruent to 1 (mod 3).

Running through similar reasoning, inputs leading to accepting state q3 will be any input containing an odd number of 1s, and a number of 0s congruent to 2 (mod 3).

From there as long as you don't need to write the set builder notation with a regular expression it should be straightforward.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that explanation, really helpful. I have just written the set builder notation using your logic. I realized that I would also have to include the cases where the input begins with odd number of 1s and number of 0s where number congruent with 2(mod3). The set builder notation is getting quite long winded though. Do you think that is okay to be so long? $$ 1^{2n}0^m:n\geq 0, m (mod3) = 1 \:||\: 1^{2n+1}0^m:n\geq 0, m (mod3) = 2 \:||\: 0^m1^{2n}:n\geq 0, m(mod3)=1 \:||\:0^m1^{2n+1}:n\geq 0, m(mod3)=2 $$

Comment: There is one key challenge to correctly writing this in set builder notation: these 1s and 0s can be in any order. So 000011 and 010010 and 001100 and 100001 all lead to the accepting state q1. Your set has to allow for the bits in these strings to permute in any way.

Comment: Hmm yes I see that now. Not sure how I can include the permutations.

Comment: $w \:\varepsilon \:(0,1)^* :\:$number of 1s is even, number of zeros congruent with 1(mod3)
$||$
$w \:\varepsilon \:(0,1)^* :\:$number of 1s is odd, number of zeros congruent with 2(mod3)

Comment: Do you think the above works using the star closure of the set of all binary strings? Or it's too wordy?

Comment: It's a little wordy, but it's valid. If conciseness isn't important, then I'd leave it as is. But if conciseness is important, I'd try replacing words with symbols where practical. I'm not sure if writing it as a regular expression would make it shorter or not, but that might be another option to try if conciseness is important.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for the help.

Comment: I just found that it is acceptable to use the notation $ n_0(w)$ which denotes the number of 0s in string w, so can use this with the modulo. I should be able to make it look a little more concise now.